# CHtml::link - how to add a html class?

Tags: yii

On docs we can read:

```
public static string link(string $text, mixed $url='#', array $htmlOptions=array ( ))
```

Question:
I don't understand what $htmlOptions means here. I don't understand how to pass from this representation to a real code.

Can anyone please provide an example about how can we generate a link with a class defined. 
Something like:

```
<a href="#" class="hello">link hello</a>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's easier than you might think, although Yii's documentation is perhaps a bit more convoluted than needs to be. However, it does say that `$htmlOptions` is

> additional HTML attributes. Besides normal HTML attributes, a few
>   special attributes are also recognized (see clientChange and tag for
>   more details.)

In essence, whatever key/value pairs you put into the array will come out as HTML attributes¹. So, what you want to do is

```
CHtml::link('link hello', '#', array('class' => 'hello'));
```

¹except the "special" values that the docs refer to, which will not end up rendered in HTML as-is but either modify the way `link` works slightly, or end up affecting the HTML in other ways.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('Link Text',array('controller/action','param1'=>'value1'), array('target'=>'_blank','class'=>'hello'); ?>
```

It will be shown as below.

```
<!--if you disabled url manager in "protected/config/main.php" the output will be -->
<a target="_blank" class="hello" href="index.php?r=controller/action&param1=value1">Link Text</a>

<!--if you enabled url manager in "protected/config/main.php" the output will be -->
<a target="_blank" class="hello" href="controller/action/param1/value1">Link Text</a>
```

To get a detailed description about CHtml in yii Check this [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/48/by-example-chtml/).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo CHtml::link("Label Text" , array("/controller_here/action_here") , array('class' => 'class_here')); ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo CHtml::link("Label Text" , Yii::app()->createUrl("/controller_here/action_here") , array('class' => 'class_here')); ?>
```